# Angular: how can I use ng-bind-html and data-ellipsis to display emoji with limited text?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display limited text, so I use data-ellipsis and data-ng-bind.
But When I start using emoji, I need to use ng-bind-html instead. So data-ellipsis does not work anymore. Could you guys help me to get them work together?

Comment: What is `data-ellipsis`..?

Comment: Are you talking about this directive? https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis

Comment: yes, I use this plug-in.@TJ